# For $p$ an odd prime and $i\ge 1$ integer there exists $\nu \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that : $(1+p)^{{p}^{i}}=1+\nu p^{i+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility, proof-explanation

With $\gcd{(\nu,p)}=1$.

I try to see it in $\pmod {p^{i+2}}$ and I obtained $1+p^{i+1}$ but the equality does not hold anymore in $\mathbb{Z}$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You just want to prove that $(1+p)^{p^i} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^{i+1}}$. Hint: use binomial theorem.

Comment: @mathworker21 I proved that fact but I must find a $\nu$ such that $\gcd{(\nu,p)}=1$

Comment: Oh ok. The binomial theorem also will work but it will require induction, as the answer below gives. The binomial theorem gives $1+p^{i+1}+A$ where $A$ is divisible by $p^{i+2}$ (you need induction to show $p^{i+2} \mid A$). So in fact you can always get $v \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induct on $i$.

For $i=0$, $(1+p)^1 = 1 + \nu_0 p^1$ with $\nu_0 = 1$.

If $(1+p)^{p^i} = 1 + \nu_i p^{i+1}$, then
$$ (1+p)^{p^{i+1}} = (1 + \nu_i p^{i+1})^p = 1 + \nu_i p^{i+2} + \sum_{j=2}^p {p \choose j} \nu_i^j p^{j(i+1)} = 1 + \nu_{i+1} p^{i+2}$$
where
$$ \nu_{i+1} = \nu_i + \sum_{j=2}^p {p \choose j} \nu_i^j p^{(j-1)i+j-2} $$
and note that ${p \choose j} p^{(j-1)i+j-2}$ is divisible by $p$.